# Load data on page scroll doesnt bot work perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on page where it will load news when it will reach to the end of page.

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() -50) {
        //if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - 100) {
        //alert("I am loading");
        GetRecords();
    }
  });
```

Problem withe the above code it that it send multiple request to the server as i have mentione `>=` in the `if condition` i tried few thing but it doesnt seem to work properlt.

When i use `==` operation and `$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()` it works fine on desktop but it doesn't trigger in mobile version.

I have header & footer in the page which i event didn't hide for troubleshooting but it still doesn't work properly

Anything which i can do to fix this issue

Comment: what's the issue ? multiple request  ?

Comment: when you call your `GetRecords()` you could disable the `scroll()` callback until the records have been retrieved.

Comment: It call the function ` GetRecords();` even if i comment `alert("I am loading");` it shows up multiple time

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing and i was facing the same problem.

What i did is create a boolean `isLoading` and pass it to `true` when request is send
and only when you get the response then change the value to `false`.

After that add your variable in your scroll position test.

**Example**

```
var isLoading = false;   

$(window).scroll(function(e){
  var maxHeight = $(document).height();
  var position = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  if(position >= (maxHeight - 50) && !isLoading)
  {
    loadArticles();
    isLoading = true;
  }
});

function loadArticles() {
    loadData()
    .then(data => {
      //some code here
      isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

[Demo link of my draft](https://jsfiddle.net/xp5we163/120/)

Comment: Great I was trying to do somthing similar but it didnot work. Let try your code.

Comment: `loadArticles()` has come error i am not able to run it

Comment: Yeah blocked cause external url but it was just for the logic. It works for me

Comment: I get following error `TypeError: loadData(...) is undefined`

Comment: Oh, on your code ? loadData is a personnal function used on my draft. You have to adapt with yours. Just add the boolean 'isLoading' logic

Comment: error is for ` GetRecords()` as i am using correct function in my code.

Comment: Hm how it could be possible if it was working before ? you just have an adding test on your scroll detection...

Comment: Below is the actually error i get `TypeError: GetRecords(...) is undefined[Learn More]`    `loadArticles http://m.website.com/en/articles/:668:9`
`<anonymous> http://m.website.com/en/articles/:662:13`
`dispatch https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:3:7485`
`add/r.handle https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:3:5603`

Comment: To my surprise function works but in console it show these error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159155/discussion-between-alexis-and-learning).